# JSP communicating with java and dynamically displaying html code

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am fairly new to JS and to JSP's, but I am having trouble with my JSP communicating with a Java class. I am not sure if I want to make the java class a bean or an applet or neither.

I have two text inputs from the user. I want the user to input two strings. After the user inputs to strings, I want them to click a button and execute the following:

- The two strings are going to be used as arguments for a java method.
- The java method is going to be executed with the two strings as arguments
- The method returns a StringBuffer (I realize that this isn't a JS supported class). The StringBuffer is HTML code.
- Display the HTML code that is returned from the java code underneath the button and input

My attempt at the code is below:

JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Button Pusher</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Compare</button>
<BR>
<dd>Path 1: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT  NAME="Path1Name" SIZE=20 ID="Path1ID"><BR>
Path 2: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Path2Name" SIZE=20 ID="Path2ID"><BR></dd>
<br>

<jsp:useBean id="mybean" class="my.MyBean" scope="session" >
<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="path1" value="pathname" />
</jsp:useBean>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var y=5;
var x=y+2;
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
var argument1 = document.getElementById("Path1ID")
demoP.innerHTML= "Display html from MyBean.compare(path1,path2) method here";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Java code:

```
package my;
public class MyBean {

private String name=new String();
private String path1 = new String();
private String path2 = new String();

public String getPath1() {
    return path1;
}
public String getPath2() {
    return path2;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setPath1(String path1) {
    this.path1=path1;
}
public void setPath2(String path2) {
    this.path2=path2;
}
public StringBuffer compare(String path1, String path2) {
    StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer(); 
    strBuff.append("<b>" + path1+"</b>"+"<i>"+path2+"</i>");
    return strBuff;
}
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the form and then get the parameters into your page. I think you need to go through some very basic tutorials on JSP. Using javascript in this way is not correct. There is no interaction between Javascript and the Java code in your JSP.

Comment: Could you suggest an approach that might allow me to complete my described task? Should I have the text boxes be a form and pass them into another JSP which calls the Java method?       Is it possible/recommended to do this all in one JSP?

Comment: Either one would work. It depends on how you want the user flow to go. If you resubmit to the same page you need to check to see if you have form parameters to see where you are in the application flow.